# ssrs get single value from dataset into parameter default value

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2008R2 and i try to get single value from dataset to use it as default value of report's parameter.

Dataset filled with this query:

```
select distinct
    o.organization_id,
    o.mean_name,
    o.short_name
from
    dbo.organization o
    inner join
        dbo.identifier i on i.organization_id = o.organization_id and
                            i.market <> 3
```

I have report's parameter `organization_id`, whose value user selects. And now I want get value of field `short_name` from dataset where field `organization_id` equal to parameter `organization_id`. But I can't do this.

I tried to use `Lookup` function like this: 
`=Lookup(Fields!organization_id.Value, Parameters!organization_id.Value, Fields!short_name.Value, "dsOrganizations")`, but server gave me error "Fields cannot be used in report parameter expressions".

I tried to make variable with this `Lookup` function, but variables can't be used in report parameters.

And now I have no idea how set parameter default value from dataset. 
I will welcome any tips or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create one more dataset with this query: `select short_name from organization where organization_id = @organization_id` and set parameter value equals to parameter `organization_id`. After there I set default value to parameter `short_name` just as "Get values from a query" and as dataset set new dataset.

I hope, that my experience will be useful to someone.